# How can I get only tags of html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, tags

How can I get only HTML tags with NodeJS ?

I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
Hi
</head>
<body>
<center id="fantastic">
Hi , hello
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to delete Hi and Hi , Hello and get only the tags, and i want remove too the id="fantastic".
Any idea? Any regular expression?

Comment: `str.replace(/>([\w\W]+?)</g,"><");` will work on valid markup

Comment: @vihan1086 - why did you change the source HTML to add indentation when none was present in the original question.  This is a question about parsing and modifying some specific HTML source so it doesn't seem appropriate to change the input the OP provided.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dandavis but if I have <a href="something.com"></a> how can I remove and get only <a></a> so removing href="something.com"?

Comment: `var ok = result.replace(/>([\w\W]+?)</g,"><");
ok= ok.replace(/ ([\w\W]+?) >/g,">");
ok= ok.replace(/ ([\w\W]+?)>/g,">");`
I made this but I don't like and don't know if work for everything. Any idea for improve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the source HTML in a Javascript string and that it is legal HTML and the HTML attributes don't contain ">" or "<" characters, this should work:

```
var source = "your html here";

var result = source.match(/<.*?>/g).map(function(item) {
    return item.replace(/<\s+/, "<").replace(/\s.*?(\/?>)$/, "$1");
}).join("");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6q0gyugd/

This uses a regex to isolate just the HTML tags into an array and then uses `.map()` to iterate through that array to remove any leading whitespace in the tag and then to remove any attributes from each tag, then joins them back into a string of HTML.

---

To be the most robust with any possible legal HTML, you may as well just use an actual HTML parser (which can be smarter than any regex can possibly be) to parse the actual HTML tags, then walk the parsed tree to output just the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a library like `cheerio` - https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: I don't want the solution, i want only a sugestion why I use that for that task.